# How to stop Outlook 2010 from blue-underlining all text in read messages?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

For some reason only some HTML-formatted emails I receive get blue-underlined like this screenshot.
This problem is not with the original message, since my co-workers do not have this underline and I see can such messages normally for a couple of seconds and then see as Outlook progressively adds underlines to each word. This underline is the same style as "incorrect syntax" when composing a new message or in Word.
How do I turn this off for the incoming messages?

[image: Example]

Comment: If you mouse over the lines, or right click them, does it give any indication about what "error" it is trying to identify?

Comment: If I right-click on that text, context menu has disabled "Make this text consistent with formatting...." It looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/NahK0.jpg).

Comment: Could you please also post the message headers as [described here](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/How_to_View_the_Complete_Message_Source_in_Outlook.htm) ?

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to see headers of that message?

Comment: I want to see how the message was constructed and its metadata. This might not help, but it completes the picture.

Comment: @harrymc your link is for older versions of outlook. in 2007 and 2010 you can get email headers without that registry here. I don't have this message anymore. However, I received another one with exactly the same problem and here are its headers http://pastebin.com/w0334yF3

Comment: Nothing in the headers - maybe the entire message as-is will contain a clue. You could for starters Save As in msg format and post (my Outlook 2007 might or might not be able to use it). Format eml will be better, but I don't think Outlook 2010 supports it. You might need to use the trial version of [MailExporter](http://www.mailexporter.net/) or some such equivalent product, but let us start first with the msg format.

Comment: Raw html of the message does not have any underlines coded in it. I'm not going to post the message as is due to it containing company related information and I'm not going to go through all the code and try to sanitize it.
Once again, that underline is not visible on the message right away. It feels like it takes a few seconds for Outlook to scan/check/whatever it before you can see them showing up line by line.

Comment: The underlining does not appear on all the text. What I wanted was to compare the attributes of text with and without. You could maybe find this out. I have subscribed to O'Reilly, but received nothing yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While other answers were helpful in directing me to the final solution, ultimately this option was in another location. Settings in MS Word have no relation here at all.

> Outlook -> Outlook Options -> Mail -> Editor Options -> Advanced ->
>   Disable "*Mark formatting inconsistencies*".

[image: Outlook options]

Comment: this disables it for Editing emails as well

Answer (score 1):

Outlook uses Word as it's editor. So it's possible you will need to adjust Word options.

I don't have an HTML message like that to try this on, but you can check in **File>Options>Advanced>Editing Options** and remove the check from **Mark Formatting Inconsistencies**.

[image]

You might have to close Outlook and reopen it for a change to take place. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hmm..But I do want this functionality when I'm _editing_, not when I'm _reading_. From what I understand, if I remove that checkmark, it'll disable for editing as well?

Comment: Hmm, I just checked my Outlook and I don't have "Editing Options" in Advanced. I have that in Word, but not Outlook. And in Word both boxes are clear just like in your screenshot.

Comment: @Mxx: To my understanding, Outlook uses the Word HTML rendering engine to display HTML mails. So I wouldn't be too surprised if a setting in Word would have an affect on this.

Comment: Like I said above, in Word I have that option disabled..

Answer (score 0):

My O'Reilly webcast notice has come in, and the display is entirely normal with no wavy lines anywhere, as shown below. The conclusion is that some setting of Outlook or of Word is responsible for these lines.

With no hands-on access to your computer, it is hard to guess what it can be.
What I suggest is to scrutinize carefully all the settings of Outlook, then of Word, trying to find
a reason. Of special interest should be all options relating to spelling or syntax of incoming mail.

If you cannot find the responsible setting, my only idea is to reset back to default setting, starting with Outlook.

For outlook : run `outlook.exe /firstrun`. You could also try using a new user profile.
For word : see [How to reset user options and registry settings in Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822005).

[image]

Comment: *sigh*..That's what I've been telling all this time. The message itself does not have these underlines. It is something in Outlook...which is why I posted the original question.

Comment: Try another Outlook profile to see whether this is really an Outlook setting.

Comment: Outlook 2010 does not have /firstrun parameter. Here's a page that lists all the available options http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-outlook-2010-HP010354956.aspx
Creating a new Outlook profile also did not fix the problem.
However, resetting Word's registry did. But it also nuked a bunch of my Outlook customizations. Now I'll be slowly restoring them back and see if any of those settings cuased this problem.

Comment: If you find out which setting, please share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

Word may still be tracking formatting inconsistencies even though the setting shows to be 'off'.

- Reboot your computer to obtain a clean state.
- After login, close any just started running programs.
- Open Outlook and compose a new message
- Within the message editor (Word) view File > Options > Advanced > Editing Options.

  **If you see check marks** in the boxes for `Keep Tracking of Formatting` and `Mark Formatting Inconsistencies` then uncheck them and Exit (File > Exit) Outlook. Re-open Outlook and test the HTML message for the presence of unwanted lines.

  **If you do not see check marks in either box** then check both options and Exit (File > Exit) Outlook. Re-open Outlook and test the HTML message. You should see lines. Compose a new message and return to the Advanced Editing Options dialog. Uncheck both `Keep Tracking of Formatting` and `Mark Formatting Inconsistencies`. Exit Outlook. Re-open Outlook and view the HTML message. Hopefully you will not see lines.

---

If the above does not succeed there are at least four remaining possibilities:

- Your outlook profile is corrupt

  > Build a new outlook profile as described by harrymc and see if the unwanted blue wavy lines persist.
- You have an add-in that is interfering with outlook

  > Start outlook from a command prompt using `outlook.exe /safe`. Does the unwanted behavior continue?
- You have an add-in that is interfering with Word

  > Start Word from a command prompt using `winword.exe /a` to disable addins and avoid loading normal.dot
  >
  > Start Word from a command prompt using `winword.exe /safe` for Safe Mode. Does the unwanted behavior continue?
  >
  > Start Word from a command prompt using `winword.exe /r` to refresh the registry settings stored for Word on the local computer.
- Your Word normal.dot template is corrupt

  > While Office and Outlook are completely closed. Backup and delete `normal.dotm`. Does the unwanted behavior continue?

Answer (score -2):

1. Go into File
2. Go into Options
3. Go into Mail
4. Go into Signatures
5. Go into Personal Stationery
6. Under Replying or Forwarding Messages, make sure the font is not set to underline.

Comment: The blue squiggly lines pictured are not font underlines.

Comment: I'm not replying or forwarding that message. They were like that in the reading pane. Furthermore, this is not font underline. It was formatting inconsistencies like as I specified in the marked answer above.